# jquery explode()

Tags: jquery

i want make function like that

```
function(data){

}
```

i want this data as this
url,email,comments

```
function($data){
foreach(explode(",",data) as $value)
var value = $("#value").val();
}
```

This code is like php. I am sure its not work but I want make this by jQuery. I made it by php

Comment: jQuery is a Javascript library, not a PHP library.

Comment: Please explain cleary, step by step, what you want exactly. The way you've asked your question now is very hard to understand and very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

[jQuery.each](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each)

to iterate through the object

Answer (score 1):

```
function(data) {
    var i, values = data.split(",");
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        var value = $("#" + values[i]).val();
    }
}
```